# Codeigniter pagination giving 404 error

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

Could you help me with my problem about pagination in Codeigniter? I have a view that lists books. I wrote some code and now I see the buttons but the content is not limited as I wished. Can't find what is wrong with the code.

That is the updated code: 
Controller:

```
public function index($offset=0){

    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/myLibrary/books/index';
    //$config['total_rows'] = 200;
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('books')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 1;
    $config['uri_segment']= 3;
    $config['attributes'] = array('class' => 'pagination-link');
    $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
    $book_list = $this->Books_model->list_books();
    $genre_list= $this->Books_model->list_genres();
    $author_list= $this->Books_model->list_authors();
    $view_data = array(
        "book_list" => $book_list,
        "genre_list" => $genre_list,
        "author_list" => $author_list
    );


    $this->db->get('books', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
    $start = isset($_GET['start']) ? $_GET['start'] : 0;
    $book_list = $this->Books_model->list_books($start, $config['per_page']);


    $this->load->view("book_list",$view_data); 
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->library('table');

}
```

Model:

```
public function list_books($limit = FALSE, $offset = FALSE){
    if($limit)
    {
        $this->db->limit($offset, $limit);
    }
    $list=$this->db->get("books")->result();
    return $list;
}
```

View:

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

I'd be so happy if you could help and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use base_url() function as a base_url for pagination unless this index function belongs to your default site controller.

Instead change your line to this:

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url('controller/method/');
```

Also the reason your data isn't limited is because you're sending start parameter as false to model

It should be:

<strike>`$data['records'] = $this->Books_model->list_books($this->uri->segment(3), $config['per_page'], $offset);`</strike>

By looking at your code, the list of books being sent to the view file is stored in the $book_list variable, so in order to limit the number of books returned alter your line to this:

```
$start = isset($_GET['start']) ? $_GET['start'] : 0;
$book_list = $this->Books_model->list_books($start, $config['per_page']);
```

And add this you your pagination config array:

```
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
```

And in your model function change this line:

```
$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
```

To:

```
$this->db->limit($offset, $limit);
```

as stated in the CI documentation

> $this->db->limit(10, 20);  // Produces: LIMIT 20, 10 (in MySQL.  Other databases have slightly different syntax)

Check here for more reference [CI Limiting](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results)

Also as a side note, by looking at your code the `$query` and `$data['records']` variables are assigned values but are never used or passed to the view file, so they don't do anything

This is how an index method in your controller should look like now:
Controller:

```
public function index($offset=0){

    $config['base_url'] = site_url('books/index');
    //$config['total_rows'] = 200;
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('books')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 1;
    $config['uri_segment']= 3;
    $config['attributes'] = array('class' => 'pagination-link');
    $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
    $start = isset($_GET['start']) ? $_GET['start'] : 0;
    $book_list = $this->Books_model->list_books($start, $config['per_page']);
    $genre_list= $this->Books_model->list_genres();
    $author_list= $this->Books_model->list_authors();

    $view_data = array(
        "book_list" => $book_list,
        "genre_list" => $genre_list,
        "author_list" => $author_list
    );

    $this->load->view("book_list",$view_data); 
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->library('table');

}
```

Model:

```
public function list_books($limit = FALSE, $offset = FALSE){
        if($limit !== FALSE)
        {
            $this->db->limit($offset, $limit);
        }
        $list=$this->db->get("books")->result();
        return $list;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed the base url as you said and 404 error is now resolved. Also updated the other codes but still datas are not limited

Comment: I have updated the codes but unfortunately nothing has changed

Comment: I have made some update to the code, please check them and let me know if it works now

Comment: `$start = isset($_GET['start']) ? $_GET['start'] : 0;
$book_list = $this->Books_model->list_books($start, $config['per_page']);` This one didn't work either

Comment: Have you also added the `$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;` also?

Comment: Yes, I've added

Comment: Can you post an update to your code so I can see all the changes ?

Comment: You made changes to your controller code, but in a wrong place. I will update my answer to show full change

Comment: What about `$start = isset($_GET['start']) ? $_GET['start'] : 0;` ?

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not working :/ I'm recieving all the data in the first page and when I click to '2' or'3' all I got is the same page again

Comment: I have update the model code, check it and see if it works

Comment: Igor, thanks for all your effort but there's still a problem. The code looks solid and even works in another codeigniter project. With the update about limit you advised I can see the first record on the page but when I click '2' or '3' all I see is the same record again

Comment: Please try and add one more line to your pagination config array:
`$config['query_string_segment'] = 'start';`

Comment: No change. By the way when I `var_dump(uri_string());` it returns a empty string as `C:\wamp64\www\myLibrary\application\controllers\Books.php:10:string '' (length=0)`

Comment: Problem is solved finally! It took me change a lot of things though, thanks for all your help Igor!

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/controller/index/page/'
```

Try to add index as method name config['base_url]. so that whenever your pagination url created it contains method name.
this happens due to index method call automatically i.e. we don't need to mention method name but in pagination url we have to pass offset parameter we must have to use full url.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I'm not getting the 404 error but the data is still not limited